# Why iOS 13.x below the 13.4 version is still using TLS 1.0/1.1 and how to force it to use TLS 1.2 and above?

Tags: ios, cordova, ssl, https, tls1.2

We are doing some research on our inbound TLS traffic and we are currently seeing a small percentage of ***iOS 13.x*** below the **13.4** version that are still using **TLS 1.0** or **TLS 1.1** .

Do you know why this recent OS is still using these deprecated protocols and how to force it to use at least the TLS 1.2 version?

Comment: I would guess behind proxies that don’t support TLSv1.2. Or bots faking user agents to pretend to be real traffic. Not much you can do about either.

Comment: Uhm..It is strange we are not seeing any 13.4 with the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

According to Cordova documentation, there is a way to control and force minimum version but it also states the minimum TLS version defaults to 'TLSv1.2'. Furthermore, this only applies to the main Cordova webview, and does not apply to an InAppBrowser webview or opening links in the system web browser.

From the config.xml file, Cordova automatically converts  and  tags to the appropriate Application Transport Security (ATS) directives.

The  and  tags support these three attributes below, which have their equivalents in ATS:

1. minimum-tls-version (String, defaults to 'TLSv1.2')
2. requires-forward-secrecy (Boolean, defaults to 'true')
3. requires-certificate-transparency (Boolean, defaults to 'false', new
   in iOS 10)

**example**:

```
<access origin='https://cordova.apache.org' minimum-tls-version='TLSv1.1' requires-forward-secrecy='false' requires-certificate-transparency='true' />
```

In iOS 10 and above, the  tag supports these three attributes below, when paired with the origin wildcard *. These attributes also have their equivalents in ATS:

1. allows-arbitrary-loads-for-media (Boolean, defaults to 'false', new in iOS 10. New in cordova-ios@4.5.0, fixed to use the proper attribute name). The old attribute allows-arbitrary-loads-in-media is now deprecated.
2. allows-arbitrary-loads-in-web-content (Boolean, defaults to 'false', new in iOS 10)
3. allows-local-networking (Boolean, defaults to 'false', new in iOS 10)

**example**:

```
<access origin='*' allows-arbitrary-loads-for-media='true' allows-arbitrary-loads-in-web-content='true' allows-local-networking='true' />
```

Source: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/guide/appdev/whitelist/

Comment: Thanks. Any hints why those versions are using Tls 1.0 or 1.1?